# WoW API and underscore.js / javascript 'Unexpected reserved word' issue

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So basically I get a JSON response from the WoW (World Of Warcraft) API:

```
            this.url="http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/"+config.realm+"/"+config.charName+"fields=achievments&jsonp=?";

            this.template = config.template.html();

            $.when(this.fetch()).then(function(response){
                console.log( response );
                self.attachTemplate( response );
            });
        },

        attachTemplate: function( data ){

            var compTemplate = _.template( this.template, data );

            console.log( compTemplate );

            this.getContainer().append( compTemplate );
        },
```

My template looks like this:

```
<h1><%=name%></h1>
<h5 style="color: black;"><strong style="color: black;"><%= class %></strong>
```

I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Apparently I can't use the word 'class' because it is a js reserved word. The API response object has a field named class. Is there any workaround apart from creating intermediate variables ?

Comment: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/430

Comment: So it is not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `data` in another object to get around the conflict caused by underscore's use of `with`:

```
var compTemplate = _.template( this.template, { 'wrap': data } );
```

Or (probably the better method), is to specify a `variable` name for the template which will tell underscore **not** to use `with` and will automatically put all the data into a object with the name you specify. This method will also make the performance *slightly* better:

```
var compTemplate = _.template( this.template, data, { 'variable': 'wrap' } );
```

Then in your template you'd have to prefix all your variable references with `wrap.`

```
<h1><%= wrap.name %></h1>
<h5 style="color: black;"><strong style="color: black;"><%= wrap.class %></strong>
```

Comment: Heh, thanks. Was wondering whether there's an alternative to wrapper objects, but that helps a lot too!

Comment: You can also just set `_.templateSettings.variable = 'wrap'` to do it globally for all underscore templates. Then you could use your original syntax without issue: `_.template( this.template, data )`. (You'd still be using `wrap.whatever` in your template)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a complet JS library to work with WOW API. It is located here: https://github.com/eduardm/wowjsapi

Comment: awesome! will try it out :)